# How to test the implementation of an instance method on a python class using unittest.mock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I have the following class:

```
class RefdataMapping(object):
    def _init_(LONG_LIST_OF_ARGUMENTS):
        # Complex stuff

    def is_hybrid_default_mapping(self, mapping):
       # Code I want to test
```

I want to test the implementation of is_hybrid_default_mapping without having to completely instantiate an object of RefdataMapping.

My humble stab at this have resulted in this:

```
def test_is_hybrid_default_mapping():
    mappings = [{"a": "*", "b": "*", "c": "*"}]
    mock = Mock(spec=RefDataMapping)
    res = mock.is_hybrid_default_mapping(mappings[0])
    assert res == False
```

but since res only returns an instance of the mocked method, the test fails.

```
FAILED tests/test_basic.py::test_is_hybrid_default_mapping - AssertionError: assert <Mock name='mock.is_hybrid_default_mapping()' id='139681656266272'> == False
```

How do I call the method without having to instantiate the class with all its complexity without adding inheritance or interfaces to this implementation?

Comment: You can call the method on the _class_ and pass "self" explicitly; there's likely a better solution but with so little context it's hard to say what it might be.

Comment: Thank you. That was very straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358062/how-to-test-the-implementation-of-an-instance-method-on-a-python-class-using-uni?noredirect=1#comment122588991_69358062), this turned out to be really simple:

Call the method using the mocked object as the self argument.

```
def test_is_hybrid_default_mapping():
    mappings = [{"a": "*", "b": "*", "c": "*"}]
    mock = Mock(spec=RefDataMapping)
    res = RefDataMapping.is_hybrid_default_mapping(mock, mappings[0])
    assert res == False
```